# R: error while reading .h5 files from R using rdhf5 package

Tags: r, rhdf5

I am new to hdf5 files. Trying to read some sample files from the below URL..
https://support.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/examples/files/exbyapi/

while trying to reading one of the .h5 files in R environment

`library(rhdf5)
 h5ls("h5ex_d_sofloat.h5")`

I am getting the below error

> Error in H5Fopen(file, "H5F_ACC_RDONLY") : 
>     HDF5. File accessability. Unable to open file.

help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was some issues with windows itself which was encrypting the hdf5 file while downloading it with default arguments. while downloading the just change the mode as "wb"..

```
file_url <- "http://support.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/examples/files/exbyapi/h5ex_d_sofloat.h5"
library(rhdf5)
download.file(url = file_url,destfile = "h5ex_d_sofloat.binary.h5",mode = "wb")
h5ls("h5ex_d_sofloat.binary.h5")


>   group name       otype dclass     dim
0     /  DS1 H5I_DATASET  FLOAT 64 x 32
```

i got this solution from biocondutor itself...
https://support.bioconductor.org/p/97311/#97362